# extract data from different database tables in spring batch

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch, xstream, spring-oxm

I'm supposed to extract data from a particular database and put it into an XML file.

But the data can only be obtained by doing **multiple select queries to different tables** of the database.

Here is my configuration:

```
<!-- Reader for getting msisdn -->
<bean id="pagingdbItemReader2"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT SUBSTR(DN_NUM,4) AS MSISDN" />
            <property name="fromClause"
                value="FROM contr_services_cap cs, directory_number d" />
            <property name="whereClause"
                value="WHERE co_id in (select co_id from contract_all where customer_id =:CUSTOMER_ID)
                        AND cs.dn_id = d.dn_id 
                        AND cs.sncode = 1 
                        AND CS.MAIN_DIRNUM = 'X'" />
            <property name="sortKey" value="MSISDN" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="CUSTOMER_ID" value="#{jobParameters['CUSTOMER_ID']}" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="10" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.ooredoo.model.inputDB.MSISDNRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Writer for getting msisdn -->
<bean id="dbItemWriter2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/DonneesFactureFromDB.xml" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="dbMarshaller2" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="Facture" />
</bean>

<!-- Marshaller for getting msisdn -->
<bean id="dbMarshaller2" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="aliases">
        <util:map id="aliases">
            <entry key="msisdn" value="com.ooredoo.model.inputDB.MSISDN" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Shall I do ALL this config (and create corresponding java classes) for EVERY query ?**

---

**EDIT:**

I've done this config to extract data from database using a query "A" (And it worked). So my question is: Am I supposed to write the same configuration (with the reader, the writer, the marshaller...etc) for EVERY query I want to execute... or can I write maybe a kind of "group of queries" that can be executed one after the other and render their results to be written in ONE XML file ???

Comment: Shall I write my own custom writer ?

Comment: Nobody has an idea for my problem :( ?

Comment: Sorry, the question is too broad. And it seems nothing to do with JAXB as you are apparently using XStream.

Comment: OK, let me specify my question: I've done this config to extract data from database using a query "A" (And it worked). So my question is: Am I supposed to write the same configuration (with the reader, the writer, the marshaller...etc) for EVERY query I want to execute... or can I write maybe a sort of "group of queries" that can be executed one after the other and render their results to be written in ONE XML file ???

Comment: Please notice that I tried to make the same configuration for a second query "B", but the result of query "A" were overwritten by the data of query "B" in the XML file. That's why I believe that making a configuration for each query is NOT the right way to do.

Comment: Please notice also that I'm really new at spring batch

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you want. (And sorry, I won't be able to help as I don't have the relevant experience in spring batch. I have edited the tags to attract the right audience, hope it helps.)

Comment: I explained want I want in my previous comments...

Comment: It is better to include the relevant information in the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63330/discussion-between-siho-and-lexicore).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create multiple readers having each queries and then chain them together using composite pattern.

HTH

Comment: Could you please provide sample code or link to support your answer?